# Can you force Arcane Armor off of someone?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer

I'm a DM and one of my party members wants to use it to be able to walk without legs so it's just armor carrying a body (were starting at 5th level if your wondering). I want a way to make this a disadvantage and basically render him useless for a battle or two for fun. I know it says that The armor attaches to you and can’t be removed against your will but i was wondering if there was a spell or some condition that would get rid of the magic on it or something in 5e, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you've accidentally made two accounts. You should go through the process of getting them [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to do this? Being rendered useless for a battle isn't my idea of "fun" personally. Is this sort of thing normal for your group?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question - Did the player ask to be sidelined, or would this be at your own whim?

Comment: I have the sense that this is being down voted because this is almost certainly bad idea in terms of everyone having fun.  However I'm not seeing a problem with the content of this post *as a Role-Playing Games SE question*.  Can someone fill me in if there is a problem with this question that warrants down-voting other than that doing this would typically fall under "the DM being a jerk"?

Answer (score 11):

#### This doesn’t sound like much fun.

In particular:

> I want a way to make this a disadvantage and basically *render him useless for a battle or two for fun.*

It sounds like this character is trying to have a bit of flavorful fun with their character’s abilities. From what I can tell, *what they are doing isn’t affecting the mechanics of the game at all*. It sounds like they are just trying to add some fun flavor to their character.

*Why in the world would you punish this?*

If you feel that this sort of RPing with the class feature is not serious enough tone-wise for your game, *this is an issue that should be discussed out of game*, not by ruining their fun in game.

I haven’t bothered to see if this is possible within the rules, because it shouldn’t be done at all. I cannot in good conscience equip you to take away someone else’s fun.

Comment: "Why in the world would you punish this?" Consider the recent "wheelchairs in DnD" controversy, and I suspect you might have your answer.

Comment: @nick012000 I’m not aware of any controversy.

Comment: Here's an article that briefly covers it from a pro-wheelchair point of view: https://www.belloflostsouls.net/2020/08/dd-haters-can-hate-but-that-combat-wheelchair-has-a-mini-now.html

Comment: @nick012000 Because people like to crap on things that are good for other people but effect themselves in no way whatsoever?

Comment: The gist of the anti-wheelchair point of view can be summed up as "this defeats my suspension of disbelief" along with a bit of "trivializing the difficulties that disabled people suffer (e.g. by allowing someone in a wheelchair to climb up stairs in their wheelchair) constitutes ableist appropriation".

Comment: "My suspension of disbelief can withstand magic, talking swords, extraplanar travel, an interactive pantheon, and a five headed dragon who is also the queen of nine hells, but wheelchairs is where I draw the line. Im not buying wheelchairs. It's too much."

Comment: All of those things are magic; wheelchairs aren't,  and if you're using magic to be making magic wheelchairs,  you could be using that magic to cure them so that they don't need wheelchairs. That's where the straining of the suspension of disbelief happens.

Answer (score 5):

#### No

> The armor attaches to you and **can’t be removed against your will**. It also expands to cover your entire body, although you can retract or deploy the helmet as a bonus action. The armor replaces any missing limbs, functioning identically to a limb it replaces.

[Arcane Armor description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#ArcaneArmor-2985531)

That's pretty cut and dry. You cannot remove it against their will. Enchantment magic of some sort may be able to force them to remove it--but that certainly wouldn't be a "reasonable request" for anything like Suggestion in combat. You'd need something like Command or Dominate Person. (see: many, many cautionary commentaries on subverting the will of player characters)

And even if you did somehow get it off of them

> You can doff or don the armor as an action.

All you have done is created a 1 action tax for them to put it back on.

#### Antimagic

You can't even shut the armor down in an Antimagic Field. The description of the armor does not say that the armor becomes Magical...and, importantly, you can Infuse your Arcane Armor, but you *cannot* infuse magic items.

Thus, Arcane Armor does not count as a magic item, and thus would continue to function in an Antimagic field.

#### A cautionary note

Make sure you know your player and that they are going to actually still have fun if you start trying to sideline them. They've already taken on the issue that they must wear their armor at all times or be crippled--which could easily be a social issue. I mean...how is the character supposed to go to a fancy ball while wearing a suit of armor...the "it fits under your clothes" feature of the Infiltrator model was removed when it went from UA to the final version.

Answer (score 1):

> The armor attaches to you and can’t be removed against your will.

The rule is pretty black and white. However the answer is there as well. It cannot be removed against your will. Arguably some magical compulsions might or might not change your will. However, under any definition old fashioned trickery works.

Consider if there were a cursed +1 plate armor, that once you attempt to don it, it turns into an animated armor and attacks! This would be a bane to any plate wearer (as donning their new armor first requires doffing their old armor). However for your particular use it could be especially troublesome if the animated armor first action is to kick away the old armor.

As others have mentioned however, the "fun" of exploiting a character physical disability would likely be questioned at many tables. It could be considered distasteful for everyone involved.

Answer (score -1):

If, as per [Guildbounty's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/181111/16003), Arcane Armor is ruled as non-magical, several options for destroying or eliminating it exist:

A  [Rust Monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17001-rust-monster) should provide at least a risk of destroying the Arcane Armor with its antennae.

The [Disintegrate spell](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Disintegrate#content) should destroy the armor, assuming it is cast on the armor (object) as opposed to the character (creature)

Finally, there is [Wish](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wish#content) — wishing the armor destroyed or wishing to retroactively undo the infusion of the Arcane Armor.

While the first is at least arguably a playable scenario not much different than posing a plate&shield tank with the possibility of losing their armor,  the latter two can easily come across as simply punishing the player for their character choices.  To me, simply disintegrating or wishing away the Arcane Armor is difficult to pull off in a way that will be fun to play; at least without a lot of preliminary leg work to set up this eventuality.

If instead, Arcane Armor is ruled to be a magical effect, then an anti-magic effect should disable it.  But again, having a DM throw in an arbitrarily powered anti-magic effect at the party can seem capricious without doing the legwork up front to establish this threat for the party.

Comment: Arcane Armor is nonmagical? You're gonna need to support that as you are saying all these effects will do something to it (outside of wish.)

Comment: @NautArch c.f. guildsbounty's answer

Comment: Guildsbounty's answer is separate from yours - and could use some more support. Your answer should be self-contained. I also am having a hard time reading "arcane" as not magical.

Answer (score -2):

"The armor attaches to you and can't be removed against your will."

"The armor continues to be Arcane Armor until you don another suit of armor or you die."

I must be the only one!I'm thinking that an unconscious person (0 hit points) does not have any "will" to prevent the armor from being removed by somebody else.

Even if removed from the "prisoner" it is still Arcane Armor, so if he escapes/over powers the guards he can put the armor back on.

However, if you insist that it requires his conscious will to remove it. His captors can and would simply bludgeon him to 0 hit points - initiating another set of death saves. If he still doesn't comply, repeat. Eventually, they won't stop the bludgeoning when he falls unconscious - thus ending the argument.

Comment: "I'm thinking that an unconscious person (0 hit points) does not have any "will" to prevent the armor from being removed by somebody else." Is there any support in the rules for this interpretation? As far as I know, in english, "will" is a word used to define one's determination to do something or act in some way. You don't loose the "will" to act in some way if you're asleep or unconscious, you simply loose the means to express that will. Besides, I think it's pretty obvious that doing something to someone while they're asleep is "against their will" by definition.